# Applet cannot load files from jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, japplet

Using Java 1.7.25(Security set to minimum, 32bit if that matters), Windows 8, Google Chrome.

I wrote an Applet which needs to load some images. Everything is packed in jar and html file looks like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <applet code="package.AppletRun.class"
           archive="appletJar.jar" width="1100" height="700">
   </applet>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried to load images using several techniques:

- `Image image = applet.getImage(applet.getCodeBase());`
- `Image image = getClass().getResource("relative/package/filename");`
- `Image image = getClass().getResource("/absolute/package/filename");`
- `Image image = getClass().getResource("filename"); //same package`
- `Image image = someStrangeThingsICantEvenRemeber();`

The problem is everything works fine (I set not to load any images) but images just don't want to load, console shows `javaNullPointerException`. In Eclipse there is no problem, applet viewer doesn't complain. How can I load images from jar(same for class files) to my applet?

What's more `applet.getCodeBase()` returns *null* and I'm 100% sure that I'm not creating *JApplet* instance myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with code, but in java(or it's security settings). You have to self-sign jar file you are using. Browser will complain with more warning windows but in the end it will let load(find, access?) files using `getClass().getResources(...)`. I have no idea what this signing change, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the jar is either self-signed or signed with a recognized certificate authority.

From [Oracle Java Applet Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html):

Deploying an Applet

To deploy your Java applet, first compile the source code, package it as a JAR file, and **sign the JAR file.** 
Signing your applet with a certificate issued by a recognized certificate authority provides your users with assurance that it is safe to run the applet. For testing purposes, you can self-sign the applet, which generates stronger security warnings when the applet is run. For production, use a valid, current code signing certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority.

To learn how to sign the jar:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Comment: "For testing purposes, you can self-sign the applet, which generates stronger security warnings when the applet is run." stronger security warnings but I wanted to weaken them.

Comment: @MichałDębski For applications and applets that do not require untrusted components, the Trusted-Only attribute should be used. No warning dialog will be displayed and an application or applet that loads a jar file containing this attribute will not load any untrusted classes or resources. Check more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html

Comment: I tried adding Trusted-Only and instead I'm getting security exception. I guess images are untrusted components or external libraries are, because with Trusted-Libraries I'm getting class not found exception.